# Ruby %() vs. ""

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I notice some people use %(string here) instead of a simple use of double quotes as "string here".  Is there any reason for this?  When I use the first layout, I usually make an array such as %w(my array here) so I don't have to use quotes and commas.

Is there a hidden rule I am unaware of?  I can't imagine why I would do this:

```
a = %(some string here)
```

instead of

```
b = "some string here"
```

The latter just seems more clearly written.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are almost equivalent, using `%()` you don't have to escape the `"` character inside the string:

```
s = %(foo "bar" baz)
# => "foo \"bar\" baz"
```

They are mostly useful when your string is full of double quotes.

Comment: Also far more readable if you are doing a lot of multiline strings like raw SQL.

Comment: This is shorthand for `%q[...]`. `%Q[...]` is the same but `#{...}` sequences will be interpolated.

Comment: @tadman Actually `%[]` is shorthand for `%Q[]`, not `%q[]`. `x = 3; %(#{x}) # => "3"`

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell, actually, for SQL and other multiline strings, it may be better to use `<<SQL`...`SQL`. Rubymine even recognizes this, and highlights it in SQL syntax :)

Comment: @UriAgassi Didn't know about Rubymine highlighting SQL when doing that. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @toro2k Ah, good to know! I usually use the long-form version to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to have double-quotes embedded within the the string itself, it can be easier to do the `%()` than to properly escape all of the double-quotes.  It may be more readable, too.